# jQuery Autocomplete returns all results (json) no matter what I write

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

No matter what you type, jquery autocomplete displays all the results from the source, even when they have contain none of the characters in the input field.

Code is as follows.

```
$('input#project-name').autocomplete({
    source: "project-list.php",
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true
});
```

And the source outputs json like this.

```
[{"value":"sdf"},{"value":"asdas"},{"value":"ANOTHERONE"}]
```

I've been googling around for a while now, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

Thanks for the replies guys, but I'm afraid I'm not getting it, sorry. I just recently started learning this stuff. My PHP currently looks like this.

```
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

$loggedIn = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '".$userID."'");
$getRow = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectUserID = '".$userID."'";

if ($loggedIn->num_rows) { // if user is logged in

    $projects = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT projectName FROM projects WHERE projectUserID = '".$userID."'")) {
        $placeholder = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $placeholder = $row;
            array_push($projects, $placeholder);
        }
        $json = json_encode($projects);
        $result = str_replace("projectName", "value", $json);
        echo $result;
    }

}
```

But as I understand it i need to include the term there somehow? Could I please get an example?

**Update 2**

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;
    $projects = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT projectName FROM projects WHERE projectName = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["term"])."'")) {
```

and now it doesnt return all. In fact, it returns the correct one, but only after you spell it out completely, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I believe when you use a url source, the source is expected to filter the results.

Answer (score 4):

More information on my comment.  Please refer to the autocomplete documentation.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Here is the key part, emphasis mine.

> > **String:** When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). **The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results.** For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.